# "Drawing" a filled ellipse made of characters in a Console application

Tags: java, c#, .net, algorithm, drawing

I want to plot a given character into a console application, shaping an ellipse.

The problem I don't know how to solve is that I only know where to draw a character once I know the angle and the radius (with Sin and Cos functions), but then I may leave gaps.

It's even more complex, because I want to "draw" a filled ellipse, not only the border.

How can I do it?

The method I want is like this:

```
DrawEllipse(char ch, int centerX, int centerY, int width, int height)
```

**Just an idea:** I may write a loop with an inner loop in the rectangle area of the ellipse and determine if a position is inside or outside the area of the ellipse.

Comment: What kind of answer do you want?  Java (with JavaFX), C#?

Comment: I think the important part is the algorithm, but in C# would be perfect!

Comment: what ellipse? axis aligned, arbitrary angle? (the prototype suggest axis aligned). You know you can convert this to circle problem and exploit `x*x + y*y <= r*r` which is ideal for filling. just scale to circle do your rectangle fill/test and all points inside rescale back to ellipse before drawing ...

Comment: Ok, you want a filled ellipse made with console characters to print on a console, like ASCII art.

Comment: I want to fill the shape of an ellipse with an arbitrary character, given the coordinates of the center and the size (width and height). The size is the size of the rectangle in which the ellipse is fit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will be a reasonable approximation.

```
public static void DrawEllipse( char c, int centerX, int centerY, int width, int height )
{
    for( int i = 0; i < width; i++ )
    {
        int dx = i - width / 2;
        int x = centerX + dx;

        int h = (int) Math.Round( height * Math.Sqrt( width * width / 4.0 - dx * dx ) / width );
        for( int dy = 1; dy <= h; dy++ )
        {
            Console.SetCursorPosition( x, centerY + dy );
            Console.Write( c );
            Console.SetCursorPosition( x, centerY - dy );
            Console.Write( c );
        }

        if( h >= 0 )
        {
            Console.SetCursorPosition( x, centerY );
            Console.Write( c );
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To start off, here is how to draw a filled circle (assuming a 80x25 console window). Someone else might know the maths to allow width and height parameters.

```
static void DrawCircle(char ch, int centerX, int centerY, int radius)
{
    for(int y = 0; y < 25; y++)
    {
        for(int x = 0; x < 80; x++)
        {
            char c = ' ';

            var dX = x - centerX;
            var dY = y - centerY;

            if(dX * dX + dY * dY < (radius * radius))
            {
                c = ch;
            }

            Console.Write(c);
        }
    }
}
```